# Execute a Query with join in two tables from different database of same MySQL Server

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I need to execute a Query(Select only) with join of two tables from different database of same server.

Eg query  will be similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.tbl_a LEFT JOIN DB2.tbl_b ON   DB1.tbl_a.fieldX = DB2.tbl_b.fieldY WHERE ....
```

Where `tbl_a`,`tbl_b` are 2 tables from 2 different database `DB1`,`DB2` respectively

**How to do that?** How can I connect to MySQL server without specifying the database in the connection string but in sql query Using `C#`.?

Comment: What's the problem? Your query should work if you have permissions on both databases

Comment: Yes you can do that. Example Query : SELECT a.userID, b.usersFirstName, b.usersLastName  FROM databaseA.dbo.TableA a inner join database B.dbo.TableB b  ON a.userID=b.userID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this question has already been answered, here is the answer :

Yes, assuming the account has appropriate permissions you can use:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM A.table t1
  JOIN B.table2 t2 ON t2.column = t1.col
```

You just need to prefix the table reference with the name of the database it resides in.

Answer (score 0):

> > I need to execute a Query(Select only) with join of two tables from different database of same server.

For this SQL User have access on both Databases.

**Query will be like this:**

SELECT * FROM [DB1].[dbo].[tbl_a] T1 LEFT JOIN [DB2].[dbo].[tbl_b] T2 ON  T1.fieldX = T2.fieldY WHERE ....

Comment: `For this SQL User have access on both Databases.` How in C#?

Comment: I mean the SQL Server User i.e UserX should have access of both the Databases. so we can access the both databases with the same creds.